# How to display umlauts in a web page?

Tags: php

Hi I was wondering what is a quick way of showing umlauts on your page? I was thinking something like the code below, but how should I do the pseudocode part?

```
$language = $_POST['language'];

if ($language = "fi" ) {
    $filename = "C:/xampp/htdocs/finnish.txt";
} else if ($language = "eng") {
    $filename = "C:/xampp/htdocs/english.txt";
} else if ($language = "swe")  {
    $filename = "C:/xampp/htdocs/swedish.txt";
} else if ($language = "rus") {
    $filename = "C:/xampp/htdocs/russian.txt";
}

$fd = fopen ($filename, "r");
$contents = fread ($fd, filesize($filename));
fclose ($fd);

$delimiter = "*";
$splitcontents = explode($delimiter, $contents);
$counter = 0;

foreach($splitcontents as $titles[$counter]) {
    //PSEUDO CODE
    CONVERT_UMLAUTS_TO_VIEVABLE_FORM($titles[$counter]);
    $counter = $counter + 1;
}
```

Comment: what has this got to do with Umlauts? We're talking about these things, right: ÄËÖÏÜ?

Comment: Use UTF-8 and you don't need to convert anything.

Comment: You seem to be storing Russian as well. Are you sure umlauts are the only characters that need special handling in your app?

Comment: No umlauts are not the only ones, but what would be a quick way of doing this?

Comment: htmlentities() did the trick. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to store and show all data in `UTF-8` encoding.

Comment: How can I make it so, that the page shows the letters in UTF-8 form?

Comment: @student: add header with charset to pages, then convert all databases(if any) to UTF-8 from your old charset, then convert your scripts too(if they contatin something, except ASCII)

Comment: You should try to find more info yourself, and if you will get any troubles you can ask about they